# How to install Jasmin SMS Gateway in Windows 10

Tags: sms, gateway, sms-gateway, jasmin-sms

I wanted to use an SMS gateway in my larval project, I chose Jasmin as my SMS gateway. I was reading the installation guide in jasmine documentation and it doesn't give enough information about how to install in windows . . . it will help a lot if you could tell me how can I install Jasmin on the windows platform.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. Jasmine sms gateway provide docker-compose which you can run with a command